# Звонок при клике на номер

Tags: mobile, вёрстка, веб-программирование

Подскажите, пожалуйста, способ, которым можно предоставить посетителю web-страницы возможность начинать звонок после клика по номеру телефона. Предполагается, что посетитель зашёл на страницу через мобильный телефон

Возможно ли такое, если номер телефона представлен не текстом, а картинкой или через cufon?

Comment: Патентные юристы яблофона за вами уже выехали! :D

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю, насколько это работоспособно, но вот `<a href='tel:123-456-7890'>Dial Me</a>` via:  [The tel URI for Telephone Numbers](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3966).

Comment: Работает на мобильных. На десктопах, правда, дело хуже, царствует нестандартная схема `callto:`. Подробнее: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164004/how-to-mark-up-phone-numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164004/how-to-mark-up-phone-numbers) (следует учитывать, что ответы старые, еще с 2009).